# Como seleccionar filas de una tabla

Tags: angular

necesito poder seleccionar múltiples filas de una tabla y recoger el id de las que he seleccionado.

He estado intentando seguir el ejemplo "Table with selection" de [Angular Material - Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) pero lo veo muy complicado. No encuentro ningún ejemplo sencillo que pueda seguir e implementar lo que necesito.
Se que estoy algo lejos de la solución, ya que una tabla no permite hacer lo que pido si no le añado alguna funcionalidad extra.

He intentado añadir otra columna mas con un `checkbox` pero no consigo saber cual selecciono.

Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano.

```
<table>
    <tr width="35">
      <th>Imagen</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Enunciado</th>
      <th>Respuesta Correcta</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let quest of data.questionshtml" [(ngModel)]="data.selected">
      <td><img src="{{quest.image}}" width="50" height="50"></td>
      <td>{{quest.id}}</td> //CAMPO QUE NECESITO GUARDAR
      <td>{{quest.category}}</td>
      <td>{{quest.statement}}</td>
      <td>{{quest.correctanswer}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Necesitaria guardar los ids en data.selected. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba utilizando (click)="myFn()" en el tr que hace la iteración.
(click) en caso de que uses Table de Angular Material.
ng-click en caso de que uses AngularJs.

```
    <tr width="35">
      <th>Imagen</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Enunciado</th>
      <th>Respuesta Correcta</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let quest of data.questionshtml" [(ngModel)]="data.selected" (click)="myFn(quest.id)">
      <td><img src="{{quest.image}}" width="50" height="50"></td>
      <td>{{quest.id}}</td> //CAMPO QUE NECESITO GUARDAR
      <td>{{quest.category}}</td>
      <td>{{quest.statement}}</td>
      <td>{{quest.correctanswer}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Necesitaría marcar de alguna forma los que son clickados, a parte de guardarlos en una variable. Y decirle al usuario los que están seleccionados.

Comment: La respuesta es buena. El `quest.id` lo puedes gaurdar en un arreglo y despues con `miArregloDeQuestId.include(quest.id)` puedes mostrar una marca de que está seleccionado. Es sencillo. Te recomiendo dos funciones. `myFn(quest.id)` Que almacena el id en el arrelgo y la otra que devuelva un boolean al encontrar una coincidencia.